# In php, beans, is it allowed to use an array to collect variables?

Tags: java, php, spring

a classic bean:

```
class Person {

    /* Read/Write property*/
    private $_firstName;

    /* Read/Write property*/
    private $_lastName;

    /* Read/Write property*/
    private $_birthdate;

    /* Read/Write property*/
    private $_weight;

    /* Read/Write property*/
    private $_height;

    public function setFirstName($value) {
        $v = trim($value);
        $this-&gt;_firstName = empty($v) ? null : $v;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstName() {
        return $this-&gt;_firstName;
    }

    public function setLastName($value) {
        $v = trim($value);
        $this-&gt;_lastName = empty($v) ? null : $v;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName() {
        return $this-&gt;_lastName;
    }

    /* Read only property */
    public function getAge() {
        /* To be implemented based on birthdate */
    }

    public function setBirthdate(Zend_Date $value) {
        $this-&gt;_birthdate = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getBirthdate() {
        return $this-&gt;_birthdate;
    }

    /* Kg */
    public function setWeight($value) {
        $this-&gt;_weight = (float) $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getWeight() {
        return $this-&gt;_weight;
    }

    /* cm */
    public function setHeight($value) {
        $this-&gt;_height = (int) $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getHeight() {
        return $this-&gt;_height;
    }
}
```

but what if I would simplify it to:

```
class Person {

    private $data = []; 

    public function setFirstName($value) {
        $v = trim($value);
        $this->data['_firstName'] = empty($v) ? null : $v;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstName() {
        return $this->data['_firstName'];
    }
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

That's all right ,just like the difference of the map and the class.

```
`class object{
  private $a,
  private ￥b
 }`
```

and

```
object['a'],object['b']
```